# Do Windows Phone devices use wear-leveling algorithms?

Tags: flash-memory

Do Windows Phone devices use wear-leveling algorithms? Or is it used only by desktop/laptop SSDs?

Is it dependent on manufacturer or on OS?

*Note*: [Wear-leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) is a technique for prolonging the service life of Flash memory.

Comment: This is normally a hardware feature, from what I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows *Mobile* has gained wear leveling [back in the days](http://pockethacks.com/new-file-system-for-windows-mobile/) ([2](http://wmpoweruser.com/new-file-system-from-windows-mobile-promises-5-times-faster-devices/)):

> the use of both static and dynamic wear leveling double the life of flash media

So, I think it's safe to assume Windows Phone would have this considered as well.

Although I don't really think one does [55 writes to the same cell per day for five years](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/142/flash-degradation-when-going-to-standby), which actually translates to a lot more years and by then the current Windows Phone 7 are probably no longer supported and/or compatible. So, whether wear leveling or not; your storage is reliable...